# Precise definition of term: *schema*

Tags: terminology, encoding-scheme

Does the term *schema*, in the context of describing a structure, refer to the actual structure of the data, or the *description* of this structure? I.e. can I talk about the schema of an entity without a *schema language*?

For example, suppose I am writing documentation for some JSON API, that always returns a particular structure, say:

```
{ 
   "name" : "jeroen",
   "age" :  28
}
```

Can I say that the *schema* for the payload returned by this API includes required values for "name" and "age"? Or does the term exclusively refer to another document that formally describes this structure using a schema language of some sort? In that case, what is another appropriate term to refer to the recurring pattern in the structure?

The Github API, has a section titled schema: http://developer.github.com/v3/#schema. However, the word schema is not mentioned in the text itself, nor do they use any schema language. This would suggest that schema is just a general term for the structure/attributes of the output. Unless they consider english as a schema language, in which case the entire page is a schema. Hmmm.

Comment: If you are writing the documentation for a JSON API then the term *schema* is not too correct: you should use "object" instead (because {"name":"...","age":...} is a JSON object) and describe the object. Furthermore "schema for an API" is not correct: remember that API stands for Application Program Interface and usually is a *set* of functions/structures/constants/objects/methods. So you must also clarify what you mean with "a JSON API that always returns a particular structure" (do you mean every function in the API?). If you want I can expand this comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to write the documentation of the structure of the JSON objects returned from your API you can follow two approaches:

1. describe the common attributes and of the objects returned by every function of your API; and then for each API function describe the specific attributes (their type, meaning, and example);
   Many APIs that use JSON to exchange data are documented using this approach: e.g. Google APIs for various services, Facebook Graph API, [Twitter API](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/platform-objects/tweets), ...
   In this case I think it is not correct to use the term "schema".
2. or you can give a formal description of the output using a schema definition language like [JSON-schema](http://json-schema.org/) (designed by the IETF) and that plays the same role of the XML schema definition language for XML.
   But I don't know if JSON-schema is an established standard (there is an active Google group, but I didn't find any "notable" example, ... ).
   In this case you should provide a valid (json-)schema for the output of each function.

   If you choose this approach, then you should say that *name and age are two required properties of the (json-)schemas of the (json-)objects returned by the functions of your APIs* (but obviously you should provide the full-schemas, too)

Comment: this is more an implementation/web-oriented question/answer relevant to stackoverflow, without a general definition of "schema" in computer science terms....